# int cannot be converted to String при создании элемента массива

Tags: java, массивы

```java
public class StringSplit {
  public static String[] solution(String s) {
    //Write your code here
    if (s.length()%2==1){
      s = s + '_';
    }
    String[] result = new String[s.length()/2];
    for (int i=0; i<s.length()/2; i++){
      result[i] = s.charAt(i*2) + s.charAt(i*2+1);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, почему элементы массива не создаются, ошибка `int cannot be converted to String` и указатель на плюсик, хотя никаких цифр нет. Как только добавляешь "" в начало строки - пропускает (подсмотрел в решении). Вот так работает:

```java
result[i] = "" + s.charAt(i*2) + s.charAt(i*2+1);
```

Comment: язык-то какой у вас?

Comment: JAVA забыл указать, но вроде видно по синтаксису))) задачка с codewars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Преобразование типов введено в язык, чтобы использовать в одном выражении различные типы данных. И соответственно были введены правила преобразования данных, с идеей, что в выражении все данные должны быть приведены до одного типа. Согласно которым данные типа byte и char приводятся к int, для выполнения операций.

Насколько я знаю, лучший способ это использование StringBuilder для конкатенации строк. Объекты в Java бывают изменяемые и неизменяемые. Объекты типа String - неизменяемые. То есть при конкатенации строк, строка не меняется, а создается новая. То есть при множественной конкатенации создается куча объектов типа Стринг, что очень ресурсоёмко. При использовании метода append объекта Стригбилдер - новая строка не создается, а редактируется объект типа Стрингбилдер.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что при арифметических операциях char неявно приводится к int.
И ты соответственно пытаешься записать в переменную типа Стринг значение int. Значением int арифметическая операция перестанет быть, как только ты туда передашь какое-то значение Стринг. Допустим: " ". Тогда это уже будет конкатенация строк, а не арифметическое сложение и ты получишь Стринг.
Для максимальной наглядности:

```
System.out.println(5 + 5 + 5); // На выходе: 15
System.out.println("" + 5 + 5 + 5);  // На выходе 555     "" - это пустая строка
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, а какой еще есть способ конкатенации букв? Добавлять "" выглядит как костыль и додуматься самому до этого решения нереально, а это новичковая задача (7 kata). Почему вообще язык со строгой типизацией допускает что String.charAt(N) может быть цифрой?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).